# Constraints in explicit signatures for monadic bindings

Tags: haskell, types, type-constraints

Let's say I have the following function:

```
loadDialog :: String -> IO MyDialog
loadDialog file = do
  Just ui <- xmlNew file
  MyDialog
    <$> xmlGetWidget ui castToWindow "w"
    <*> xmlGetWidget ui castToButton "b"
```

where

```
xmlGetWidget :: WidgetClass widget => GladeXML -> (GObject -> widget) -> String -> IO widget
```

Now I want to capture the following xmlNew/xmlGetWidget usage pattern:

```
widgetBinder :: WidgetClass widget => FilePath -> IO ((GObject -> widget) -> String -> IO widget)
widgetBinder file = do
  Just ui <- xmlNew file
  return $ xmlGetWidget ui
```

Which should allow me to write:

```
loadDialog file = do
  bind <- widgetBinder file
  MyDialog
    <$> bind castToWindow "w"
    <*> bind castToButton "b"
```

The problem is, it doesn't typecheck (exact error [here](http://pastebin.com/mCrXYQta)). I've thought it's possible to provide generic signatures to bindings explicitly, but it seems this is not the case for monadic bindings since the following doesn't typecheck as well (even with RankNTypes, error [here](http://pastebin.com/wVevbT0A)):

```
loadDialog file = do
  bind :: WidgetClass w => (GObject -> w) -> String -> IO w
       <- widgetBinder file
  MyDialog
    <$> bind castToWindow "w"
    <*> bind castToButton "b"
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Can we get the exact error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clunky-but-workable solution is to throw your function into a `newtype`:

```
newtype Binder = Binder (forall w. WidgetClass w => (GObject -> w) -> String -> IO w)

widgetBinder :: FilePath -> IO Binder
widgetBinder file = do
  Just ui <- xmlNew file
  return $ Binder (xmlGetWidget ui)

loadDialog file = do
  Binder bind <- widgetBinder file
  MyDialog
    <$> bind castToWindow "w"
    <*> bind castToButton "b"
```

Or something like that...

Comment: Wow, it works, and even quite comfortable to use at call-site. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is occurring because the concrete choice of `widget` differs between `castToWindow` and `castToButton`. When the type-checker tries to determine the type of `bind` it tries to use information about its application in both settings and see that they conflict. In other words, there is too little polymorphism.

To avoid this, you will need an explicit signature and `RankNTypes`, as you've tried.

```
loadDialogue' :: (forall w. -> WidgetClass w => (GObject -> w) -> String -> IO w)
              -> IO MyDialogue
loadDialogue' bind = MyDialogue
                       <$> bind castToWindow "w"
                       <*> bind castToButton "b"

loadDialogue :: String -> IO MyDialogue
loadDialogue file = widgetBinder file >>= loadDialogue'
```

Note that the `forall` contained locally to the input function ensures that that function is defined polymorphically and thus instantiated individually at each site.

As a simpler example, we can try (and fail) to define `poly`

```
poly :: (Int, Double)
poly = let f = (+1)
       in (f 1, f 1.0)         -- typecheck fail!
```

which errors out because we cannot unify `Int` and `Double`, yet must in order to type `(+1)`. If we explicitly ask for the typechecker to delay instantiating (+1), however

```
poly :: (forall n . Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
poly f = (f 1, f 1.)

>>> poly (+1)
(2, 2.0)
```

We are fine.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work either: http://pastebin.com/96mCr9e4.

By the way, it seems, monadic bindings should desugar to something equivalent (... >>= \\(bind :: forall w . ...) -> ...).

Comment: It ought to be workable in a similar way to the newtype solution, but may require changing other annotations. The newtype is more secure since if the bind function gets instantiated anywhere then it cannot be wrapped into the newtype.